# Python micro service with socket + subprocess

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess

I'm using python socket and subprocess to build a micro service that:

1. Passing input from socket to a java program
2. Get the result from system output and write back to the socket

The result turns out to be unsatisfying: When the socket request too fast,  it will cause two issue:

1. The result may not be in the same order as input
2. The socket may not close by itself, and block the future requests.

Here's my code below. Any ideas on how to improve it? Thanks!

```
#Init the socket, bind to port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))

#Init the service as a subprocess 
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

def clientthread(conn):
    while True:
        #waiting and accepting new input
        data = conn.recv(1024)

        #send the request to the subprocess
        p.stdin.write(data)
        p.stdin.flush()

        #get the results and return it to the client
        result = p.stdout.readline()
        conn.sendall(result)
        conn.close()

while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

s.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things wrong with your code:

1. You're only creating a single subprocess but then every time you get a new connection, you're starting a new thread. Then all the threads are handing input to the same subprocess. They're all in a race to see who can give the next bit of input to the subprocess. And then racing to see who can get the next result out. A thread might "lose" the input race but "win" the output race so that the result it got out of the subprocess doesn't match the input. (This probably explains your ordering issue.) You either need to create a subprocess per thread, or serialize access to the subprocess.
2. You're making the assumption that your input data (from `conn.recv`) will be received in its entirety. TCP makes no such guarantee. So if your input is more than a single character, you would need accumulate data in some way (loop while "end-of-input not reached").
3. You're assuming that you *will* get data. If your client is disconnected for some reason, you will get EOF (an empty string) from `conn.recv`. Then you will write and flush an empty string (zero bytes) to `p.stdin` which is a no-op. Your subprocess will then wait forever (as will your thread since it's reading the output of the subprocess).
4. You're making the assumption that whatever you did receive from the socket is sufficient as the complete input to the subprocess you're invoking and that it will recognize that (you didn't close its `stdin` so how will it know?). That *might* be valid if you know you received the entire input and that a single blob of input (a single line or whatever) will always be exactly what your subprocess expects.
5. You're assuming that a single line is all that will ever be produced as output from the subprocess - since you only do a single `readline`.
6. You haven't checked to see whether the subprocess produced any output. If it does not, you will (again) get EOF and an empty string. You will then give an empty string to `conn.sendall` (also a no-op).
7. After sending, you're closing the connection to your peer (`conn.close`). However, you don't exit from your infinite loop, guaranteeing that you will get an exception the next time through the loop.